# how to restore data in an angular 2 app if POST fails

Tags: angular

I'm building an Angular 2 app where there are `input` fields (such as username, phone number) two-way binded to variables. After user updates the fields and click `Save`, a `POST` request will be send to the server. My question is that, how should i revert the values of the variables if that POST request fails to update the database?

Two approaches come to mind:

1. the server returns the current state for that user in the POST response regardless of save success or failure, so the app can always use that state. However, no state will be returned if say, the server is down.
2. inside Angular app, have a duplicate data structure that stores the previous state. if the post fails for whatever reason, restore by using that backup data. This always works but seems kinda wasteful, because it doubles the storage.

Does Angular 2 have anything built-in to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach sounds great (because you will always get the latest valid state of your entity) but requires adding such implementation to all affected endpoints of the backend api and some times you may not even have access to the source.

You can implement the second option in a simple way and works great - most of the time at least! So you can have say `profile` object which is the current state from the db:

```
var profile = {'name': 'john', 'surname': 'smith', 'age': 30};
```

and `profileForm` which is the 2-way binded state to the form. Just before presenting the form to the user use `angular.copy` to copy the original to the form one:

```
var profileForm = {};
angular.copy(profile, profileForm);
```

If the `POST` was successful, only then update the source object:

```
profile = profileForm;
profileForm = null;
```

This way not only you never loose the source object, you also have the failed values in a different one which lets you display user input with validation errors performed on the server-side. (e.g. username exists)

Comment: This question is about angular 2. `$scope` is an ng1 construct that (thankfully) does not exist in ng2

Comment: Sorry I misread the question, however as you pointed out also, ng2 obviously doesn't provide built-in functionality for this, so my answer is still relevant since it's plain js, and generic enough to apply to either situation. Thanks for the downvote!

Answer (score 1):

> This always works but seems kinda wasteful, because it doubles the storage.

Unless you're storing some *big-ass* usernames and phone numbers in these inputs, you're over-optimizing here. The storage cost of a few simple strings is negligible - go with the approach that makes the most sense (i.e. results in the clearest and most understandable code), and that works the best.

Given only what you've told us, IMHO this is almost certainly going to be the second approach: It's a well-understood pattern, and it sidesteps the question of what to do when the server is unreachable (a question that you *will* have to answer, and would be quite difficult to answer without implementing some form of the second approach).

ng2 doesn't have anything "built-in" explicitly for this purpose, but there are any number of ways to implement it either declaratively (preferred) or imperatively.

Comment: thanks for the reply! can you elaborate more on "declarative" vs "imperative" approaches? what are the pros and cons for each? thanks!

Comment: @dragon_cat you're welcome! That's a very big, and very different, question... It's one I'd actually really like to answer, but it most definitely deserves it's own question - feel free to post it and I'll talk to you there :-)